# Cannot Deactivate CPQ Contract Generation

Tags: opportunity, cpq, contracts

We were Using CPQ in our org. But Now we have shifted to Deal Hub.

For Old data to sustatain, we have our CPQ package installed and working.

The only problem that is coming is when Opportunity is closed won CPQ fires trigger to create a contract.

When it cannot find a primary quote it Sends an error mail as:

"*The following error occurred during contract creation. Please provide the following information to your Salesforce CPQ Admin:
Error type: SBQQ.ContractService.ContractServiceException
Reason for error: A primary quote is not specified for this opportunity. Please make sure you have the primary checkbox selected in order to generate contract for your quote.
Stack Trace:
(SBQQ)*"

I tried to check which field updates are triggering the contract generation. So found 'sbqq__contracted__C' field on opportunity on getting checked fires contract generation.

So i wrote a process builder to uncheck the field if Opportunity is closed one and no primary quote is found.

This worked succesfully and the 'sbqq__contracted__' field did not check to true.

Still I recieved the same error email.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't standard functionality to check the `sbqq__contracted__c` when an opp is closed won. You are only making the problem worse by adding a process builder to uncheck it. Process builder always fires in an "after" context, so it won't help here.

Look in your org for some automation that might be checking that field. One option is to use https://happysoup.io/ to look for dependencies.